# Trouble aligning widgets in a Row in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 2 text fields and a button in a row. I would like to align them using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround`. Here is my code

```
Widget _headerRow(BuildContext context) {
final fixturesListProvider = Provider.of<FixturesListProvider>(context);
return Container(
  child: Row( // <- this is the row I want aling
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
      _weekNumberField(fixturesListProvider),
      _leagueField(fixturesListProvider),
      _getFixturesButton(fixturesListProvider, context)
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

This is the result[image]

I have noticed that matter what alignment I use the widgets are placed end to end on the screen with no space between them, even when I have the phone in landscape.

Here are the widgets.

The button

```
RaisedButton _getFixturesButton(
  FixturesListProvider fixturesListProvider, BuildContext context) {
return new RaisedButton(
    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    child: new Text("Fixtures"),
    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(_showSnackBar(fixturesListProvider.getWeekNumber())));
}
```

Week number text field:

```
 Widget _weekNumberField(FixturesListProvider fixturesListProvider) {
return Flexible(
  child: TextField(
    onChanged: (text) => fixturesListProvider.setWeekNumber(text),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration:
        InputDecoration(labelText: "Week Number"),

  ),
);
```

}

And finally the league text field:

```
Widget _leagueField(FixturesListProvider fixturesListProvider) {
return Flexible(
  child: TextField(
    onChanged: (text) => fixturesListProvider.setLeague(text),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    decoration:
        InputDecoration( labelText: "League"),
  ),
);
```

}

How do I use `MainAxisAlignment` to align my widgets in a row?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: Something like the MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround example from this page: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Comment: I would also like to know why my MainAxisAlignment.*s  are not having any effect on the widgets inside my row.

Answer (score 0):

Your widgets take all the available width space. Put some space between them like this:

```
Widget _headerRow(BuildContext context) {
final fixturesListProvider = Provider.of<FixturesListProvider>(context);
return Container(
  child: Row( // <- this is the row I want aling
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(width: 24),
      _weekNumberField(fixturesListProvider),
      SizedBox(width: 24),
      _leagueField(fixturesListProvider),
      SizedBox(width: 24),
      _getFixturesButton(fixturesListProvider, context)
      SizedBox(width: 24),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Or if you don't want to specify the width:

```
Widget _headerRow(BuildContext context) {
final fixturesListProvider = Provider.of<FixturesListProvider>(context);
return Container(
  child: Row( // <- this is the row I want aling
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
      Flexible(flex: 3, child: _weekNumberField(fixturesListProvider)),
      Flexible(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
      Flexible(flex: 3, child: _leagueField(fixturesListProvider),
      Flexible(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
      Flexible(flex: 3, child: _getFixturesButton(fixturesListProvider, context)),
      Flexible(flex: 1, child: SizedBox()),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Don't forget to remove `Flexible` from your methods that return the `TextField`.